# Asexual reproduction by secondary mycelium in basidiomycetes

Tags: mycology

I'm studying in class 11 and the the following line was mentioned in my textbook: "Dikaryophase or secondary mycelium may multiply by different types of spores - chlamydospores aecidiospores, uredospores, teleutospores." My teacher told me that in secondary mycelium, karyogamy takes place and 4 basidiospores are formed by meiosis. Where does aecideospores, uredospores etc, come into the picture?

Comment: Those spores are produced by different groups. E.g uredospores by Rusts; which have two dikaryotic spores. There are different sorts of spores produced even by the one species at different times.

Comment: It’s really complex.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.